# Paging issue on JS slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have set up a JS slider using jquery at:
http://jsfiddle.net/indigoclothing/H4MW9/21/

It works well except the the paging links (i.e. 1, 2, 3) don't work.

I used this tutorial http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/automatic-image-slider-w-css-jquery/ but had to change $ to jQuery as was conflicting with another script.

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo in your last event assignment:

```
jQuery(".paging a").click(function() {    
        jQueryactive = jQuery(this); //Activate the clicked paging
        //Reset Timer
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
        rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
        rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
    });
```

`jQueryactive` should be `$active` so function should be:

```
jQuery(".paging a").click(function() {    
        $active = jQuery(this); //Activate the clicked paging
        //Reset Timer
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
        rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
        rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
    });
```

Comment: I'll bet this was the result of an over-zealous find-and-replace of "$" with "jQuery". :-)